# How do I store a file into a variable?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to build a custom Python library with Requests for a file/text hosting website, and I'm kind of stuck on how to store a file to a variable, and then submit it.

Here's an example of what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import requests
import string

def create_file():
    file = open('file.zip')

    requests.post('http://website.com/file', data={'file': file, 'private': 0, 'mature': 0})
```

Comment: and never ever call a variable 'file'

Comment: In local scope shadowing a builtin that's pretty much unused is not a big deal. The fact that he relies on the GC to close the file is worse.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments say, you could easily get your answer by simply trying this one out. It should work if you read the text from the file first.

However, here's a tip that might be better for file IO in python. The with statement can automatically open a file and associate a name to it.

```
with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
```

Then after you're done the file, `with` automatically closes it.

```
>>> f.closed 
True
```

[More from the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are trying to send the file object itself. You need to read the data from the file before you can send it. Try replacing this:

```
fdat = open('file.zip')
```

With this:

```
fdat = open('file.zip').read()
```

And then send `fdat` to your web service on the next line.

Comment: So, `def create_file():
 open_file = open('durkadurk.txt').read() 
 
 requests.post('http://website.com/upload', data={'file': open_file})` will work? Sorry for the horrible formatting. I ask if it would work because I have no knowledge of how to confirm it within the script.

Comment: @BrandonJackson: It shou;d. Just understand that your `open_file` variable is not any kind of a file. It is the contents of a file.

Comment: So it would be the content of the text file, rather than the text file itself?

Comment: @BrandonJackson: yes. It's just an important conceptual distinction .

Comment: Sorry for the amount of questions, but just to be sure. If there was an HTML file input tag, and I used requests like I did in the first comment (as any file extension by the way, not just .txt), it would upload the file to the server just as if I did it by myself in my browser?

Comment: According to the 'requests' documentation here: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file it is correct syntax to pass in an open file handle. urllib2 works the same way

Comment: @BrandonJackson: It should.